# Clickhouse convert table with json content each row into table

Tags: clickhouse

I have tried to transform json in rows into a table with this json fields. After looking at Clickhouse documentation I cound't find some clickhouse FUNCTION that can handle this task

Here is the table with the

| col_a |
| --- |
| {"casa":2,"value":4} |
| {"casa":6,"value":47} |

The proposal is to transform using only Clickhouse SQL (CREATE WITH SELECT) int this table

| casa | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 47 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bclickhouse%5dpivot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70257182/how-to-make-pivot-wider-r-pivot-pandas-in-clickhouse-by-mutating-part-of-t

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306158/pivot-in-clickhouse/62306508#62306508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    '{"casa":2,"value":4}' AS j,
    JSONExtractKeysAndValuesRaw(j) AS t
┌─j────────────────────┬─t────────────────────────────┐
│ {"casa":2,"value":4} │ [('casa','2'),('value','4')] │
└──────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┘

SELECT
    '{"casa":2,"value":4}' AS j,
    JSONExtract(j, 'Tuple(casa Int64, value Int64)') AS t,
    tupleElement(t, 'casa') AS casa,
    tupleElement(t, 'value') AS value
┌─j────────────────────┬─t─────┬─casa─┬─value─┐
│ {"casa":2,"value":4} │ (2,4) │    2 │     4 │
└──────────────────────┴───────┴──────┴───────┘
```